# SharePoint 2010 MUI

Tags: 2010, quick-launch, web-template

I have created a web template from scratch which is based on the OOTB Team Site. Essentially, I have copied over the Onet.xml content of the OOTB Team Site and used it as -it - is in the Onet.xml of my custom web template. My VS project does not have any other features or components except for the one which deploys the web template.

I am able to create sites successfully using this template. I have also enabled the MUI settings (Site Settings -> Language Settings -> Select alternate languages). However, I am facing an issue while switching between the selected languages. I observe that some of the components on the page, like some of the Quick Launch links remain in the default language even though I choose an alternate language from the welcome control.

As mentioned earlier, the onet.xml of my web template is essentially same as that of the OOTB team site. While the language of the Quick Launch links change in the OOTB team site, they do not change for the sites created using my web template. Also please note, its only some of the Quick launch links that dont change.

[image: MUI for Quick Launch]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a third-party product such as PointFire, the translations for the Quick Launch links and the translations for the list and library names are kept in two different places.

To edit the Quick Launch link translations, go to Site Settings on the Site Actions menu, then under Look and Feel select Quick launch.  On this page you can toggle the language using the language switch in the personal menu and see which ones are translated and which are not.  For those that are not, click on the edit icon next to them, and on the Edit Navigation Link page, select the language that is not being translated.  Edit the description field and click OK to save it.  The language of the UI at the time that it is being saved determines which language version is being saved.  If there are several languages you will have to save once for each language.

For the list or library name itself, which can be different from the menu item that points to it, go to the list/library and select List/Library settings from the list/library tab of the ribbon.  Select "Title, description, and navigation".  On the page that lets you edit the name, again select the correct language from the personal menu.  Edit the name and the description fields and click Save to save them.  The language of the UI at the time that it is being saved determines which language version is being saved.  If there are several languages you will have to save once for each language.